# Using variables from a database like source

Tags: extensions, database, mysql, variable

I have a google sheet (no, the data does not need to permanently reside there.) Which contains data for T-Shirts of my design

```
Name            Source                  Thumbnail           Commision  Description                         SSid
Puzzle Piece    \Puzzle\PuzzlePiece.ai  PuzzlePiece.png     $1.00       Just another piece of the puzzle    10369732
Puzzle Piece    \Puzzle\PuzzlePiece.ai  PuzzlePiece1d.png   $1.00       Just another piece of the puzzle    10369731
```

I have over 50 entries like this so far and i plan on making articles based on everyone of them. I found a the extension NoNumber Content Templater v4.8.2 which, while useful, doesnt fit the need im looking for. How can I refer to a table/database of data with creating articles? Create an extra table in mySql?

*Rough* example
This is [SHIRT-NAME] which you can see picture from [/image/PICTURE-THUMBNAIL]. [DESCIPTION].Click [HYPERLINK-BASED-ON-SSID]

All of the variables in brackets would refer to one of the id's in the *database*. This content is not meant to be dynamic ( perk but not the focus of my question. )

[Creating variables inside article text](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/2410/creating-variables-inside-article-text) but does not fit my needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not that clear you are after here, and I don't think that there is going to be an easy and one-go way. You probably have to look for a 3rd party extension, but it is recommended to make a descriptive explanation of what you want to achieve. At the end, this could be an [e-commerce component](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/e-commerce) working as a product catalogue, or maybe a [tables/spreadsheets](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/news-display/tables-a-lists) extensions could work.

But generally, you will need a way to manage/update/create new records in a database table and then have a way to call them in your content. 
If you want to use brackets that will be translated into content from the database, then I guess you will need a content plugin and that the "variables" inside the brackets should be unique.

I mentioned an e-commerce extension, because it may provide a way to maintain your "catalogue" and many of them come with content plugins, which you could use/fork in order to display data from their tables in content.

Similarly, this could be also possible with a [CCK](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/authoring-a-content/content-construction) and a content plugin, that will let you call text from custom fields. Probably you will need to write your own plugin.

Comment: This will not be an e-commerce solution. I am just trying to build articles using user-defined variables. The articles will link to another site which will handle the e-commerce portion. I will try searching extensions but searches for "Articles database variables" usually leads me astray. They will not be dynamic. Just exist to streamline the article creation process. Looking for something more efficient than copy/paste

Comment: I mentioned e-commerce extension, because it may provide a way to maintain your "catalogue" and many of them come with content plugins, which you could use/fork in order to display data from their tables in content.

Comment: Good to know. Will advise

Comment: I would definitely suggest using a CCK to do this which will allow you to have custom field groups, making it easy for you to add structured data in your website. Plus these fields can be switched according to a particular category, etc making it much easier to make custom views for different item groups.

Comment: While it is not exactly what i was looking for the best answer is to find a CCK or other extension instead of trying to reinvent the wheel. In my case I am using FlexiContent.